# Jquery poll request only if variable != 'something'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        (function poll(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                var process_id = $("#form3_progress_process_id").val();
                if(process_id != 'undefined') {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "grab.php",
                        data: "action=step3_progress&process_id=" + process_id,
                        success: function(data){
                            console.log("successful");
                        }, dataType: "json", complete: poll, timeout: 30000 });
                }
            }, 2000);
        })()
    });
</script>
<input type="hidden" id="form3_progress_process_id" value="undefined">
```

What i want is that it only sends the query if the value from the input **form3_progress_process_id** is not '**undefined**'.

At the start it is "**undefined**" but after some time it get's changed with jquery.

However, the above code does not work for any reason. It does not start sending the request after the value has been changed.

What did i wrong?

Comment: try `if (!process_id) {`

Comment: use `typeof` as such `if(typeof process_id != 'undefined')`

Comment: the value will be undefined only if the element was not found else it will be an empty string

Comment: Guys take a look at the input value. I set it manually to "undefined". I tried it before with the typeof method but does not work either.

Comment: Hi Michael, I have the solution, I added another answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will fire only if the `input` changes in the first 2 seconds from the begining. You should add a call to the poll method in your `else`, so the cycle doesn't break:

```
$(function() {
    (function poll(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            var process_id = $("#form3_progress_process_id").val();
            if(process_id != 'undefined') {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "grab.php",
                    data: "action=step3_progress&process_id=" + process_id,
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log("successful");
                    }, dataType: "json", complete: poll, timeout: 30000 });
            }else{
                poll();  ////Add this!!
            }
        }, 2000);
    })()
});
```

Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia

Comment: Thanks that works. is there a way to wait 2 seconds before calling it again as it normally would? Thanks

Comment: It will wait 2 seconds, because in the next call it will also enter to the `setTimeout` :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless your hidden input changes within the 2 seconds, the timer will not fire again.
change to `setInterval`

```
 setInterval(function(){
            var process_id = $("#form3_progress_process_id").val();
            if(process_id != 'undefined') {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "grab.php",
                    data: "action=step3_progress&process_id=" + process_id,
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log("successful");
                    }, dataType: "json", complete: poll, timeout: 30000 });
            }
        }, 2000);
    })()
});
```

Comment: I do not want to use setInterval. I want to use long polling.

Comment: OK fine, the only time your function checks the the value of the input is 2 seconds after it is called.

Comment: But if i remove the check it keeps checking every 2 seconds. Why does the check affect this?

Comment: you are calling the same function inside the function "poll"